# Dask dataframe has no attribute '_meta_nonempty' while merging large CSVs in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I tried Pandas with:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("csv2.csv")
my_keys = ["my_id", "my_subid"]
joined_df = pd.merge(df1, df1, on=my_keys)
joined_df.to_csv('out_df.csv', index=False)
```

And got a memory error after some grinding.

Next I tried Dask:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf1 = dd.read_csv("csv1.csv")
ddf2 = dd.read_csv("csv2.csv")
my_keys = ["my_id", "my_subid"]
joined_ddf = dd.merge(ddf1, ddf2, on=[my_keys])
joined_ddf.to_csv('out_ddf.csv', index=False)
```

And I got the rather cryptic:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_meta_nonempty'
```

Which [the doc](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html#metadata) mentions might happen (I'm guessing because of expensive type inference or something as happens in Pandas). But after messing with manually setting the metadata using the types from pandas, trying `from_pandas()` and not getting anywhere I'm thinking Dask isn't the way to go.

What's next? If there isn't a trick to metadata is my best bet to use `sqlalchemy` and `df.to_sql` to offload the join into an external db? I stayed away from the plain `csv` module due to the multiple indices in the join.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you put my_keys in a list when you use it as the argument in dask code, and not in pandas code?

Comment: Haha oops. I actually didn't do that in my code, that's a typo should be just `dd.merge(ddf1, ddf2, on=my_keys)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followup: dumping to Postgres was pretty painless though dataframes still seem cleaner to me.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df1 = pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("csv2.csv")

engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:passwd@localhost:5432/mydb')
df1.to_sql('tableOne', engine)
df2.to_sql('tableTwo', engine)

query = """
  SELECT *
  FROM tableOne AS one
  INNER JOIN tableTwo AS two
  ON one.subject_id=two.subject_id
  AND one.subject_sub_id=two.subject_sub_id
  ORDER BY
  one.subject_id,
  one.subject_id
  """
df_result = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
df_result.to_sql('resultTable', engine)
df_result.to_csv("join_result.csv")
```

Will have to try Dask again in the future.